# Slack API triggering action event for element in input block

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

My Slack app sends a radio-button question to the users. The app is built using [bolt-js](https://slack.dev/bolt-js/tutorial/getting-started). The radio buttons are inside an `input` block (ref: [Slack Block Kit](https://api.slack.com/block-kit)).

According to [bolt-js reference](https://slack.dev/bolt-js/reference) for the method `app.action`:

> ... Note that action elements included in an `input` block do not trigger any events.

However, I still receive events on the `app.action` listener from elements that are inside the input block.

The code for sending the message is this:

```js
await client.chat.postMessage({
  "channel": channelId,
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "input",
      "label": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Some question"
      },
      "element": {
        "type": "radio_buttons",
        "options": [
          {
            "text": {
              "type": "plain_text",
              "text": "Option A",
            },
            "value": "value-0"
          },
          {
            "text": {
              "type": "plain_text",
              "text": "Option B",
            },
            "value": "value-1"
          },
        ],
        "action_id": "some_action",
      }
    }
  ],
  "text": "Some Text"
});
```

I have tried:

- Removing the `app.action('some_action')` listener for this particular action. With this, the app logs show the following error:

> [ERROR]   An incoming event was not acknowledged within 3 seconds. Ensure that the ack() argument is called in a listener.

- Removing the `"action_id": "some_action"` line from the block json. I still get the above mentioned error in the logs.
- Explicitly setting `"dispatch_action": false` in the block json (which is `false` by default according to the [input block reference](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks#input_fields)). The event is still triggered.

I do not want the event to be triggered. What am I doing wrong?